# nslookup DNS Request Timed Out

Tags: debian, dns, firewall

I can't check the DNS, cause I use firewall in my server.
How to fix it?, I have a server.

[DNS Request Timed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvz7j.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add exception for DNS Port (for query) in your firewall. If this doesn't work elaborate your setup so that I will try to give a clear answer.